# Why would an interface implement another interface?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, interface

I was looking at the declaration of `List<T>` and saw that it implements `IList<T>`, `ICollection<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`(among others).

Then I went to look the definition of `IList<T>` and saw that it implements `ICollection<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`.

What's the point of an interface implementing another interface if they work just as "contracts" and we write no *real* code at them?

Is this implementation cumulative? If it is, since `IList<T>` implements `ICollection<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`, `List<T>` shouldn't implement only `IList<T>`?

Sorry if my question is confusing, I'm a litte bit puzzled right now.

Comment: It's for readability. You don't need to go further to see the most important contracts. It also ensures the contracts are not changed significantly if `IList<T>` ever stops implementing `ICollection<T>`

Comment: actually an interface doesn't implement anything but it can inherit from other interfaces

Comment: @zerkms: You should make that an answer!

Comment: @minitech: it will duplicated in few minutes, it was asked and answered number of times here.

Comment: For the question *"List<T> shouldn't implement only IList<T>"*, the reference source http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs shows the actual implementation.  The fact that VS shows IEnumerable, ICollection, etc. is just VS being goofy, the programmer who wrote `List<T>` didn't explicitly write the implementation statement.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> What's the point of an interface implementing another interface if
>   they work just as "contracts" and we write no real code at them?

Interfaces support inheritance and facilitate polymorphism in the same way that classes do. An `IList<T>` is also an `ICollection<T>`, in the same way that a `TextBox` is a `Control`.

> Is this implementation cumulative? If it is, since IList implements
>   ICollection and IEnumerable, List shouldn't implement only
>   IList?

As others have pointed out, this is mostly for readability and maintainability. Yes, inheritance is cumulative. But, when a class implements multiple interfaces that contain members with the same signature, it only needs to define one member for all implementations. [Explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) may be used to explicitly define a member for a given implementation.

Answer (score 8):

At the very least it reduces redundancy.

```
public interface INamedObject { string Name { get; } }
public interface IValuedObject<T> { T Value { get; } }
public interface INamedValuedObject<T> : INamedObject, IValuedObject<T> { }
```

Is better design than:

```
public interface INamedObject { string Name { get; } }
public interface IValuedObject<T> { T Value { get; } }
public interface INamedValuedObject<T> {
   string Name { get; }
   T Value { get; }
}
```

Also, in the latter case, notice that an `INamedValuedObject<T>` is now neither an `INamedObject` nor an `IValuedObject<T>`.

You can read the former case as "Something that is an `INamedValuedObject<T>` is something that is an `INamedObject`, an `IValuedObject<T>`, and also has the following elements".